# Checking the return value from a method for an HRESULT of S_OK

Tags: c#, hresult

How can I compare the value returned from a method with `HRESULT`? I tried this but it is not working:

```
FPropStg.DeleteMultiple(1, psProp) == VSConstants.S_OK
```

The type defintion for [DeleteMultiple()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is:

```
HRESULT IPropertyStorage.DeleteMultiple(Ulong, Propspec)
```

I have written `VSConstants.S_OK`. Is there a way I can write `S_OK` directly? I made an attempt to do so but got an error that indicated that `S_OK` does not exist in the current context.

I also checked `HRESULT` against the [Windows common system-wide codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But the value I am receiving for `HRESULT` is not in that list. Note that I have included the namespaces `System.Exception` and `System.Security.Cryptography.StrongNameSignatureInformation`.

All that said, I basically have two questions:

1. Is there a way to write `S_OK` instead of `VSConstants.S_OK`?
2. How can I compare the return value of a method with `S_OK`?

```
HRESULT hr = FPropStg.DeleteMultiple(1, psProp);

if (hr == S_OK) // S_OK does not exist in the current context...
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if you set **PreserveSig** to **false**? Something like this:

You declare the function similar to this (I made it up, I don't know the exact signature...but you do)

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteMultiple", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void DeleteMultiple(ulong cpspec, PropSpec[] rgpspec);
```

and call it this way

```
try
{
    FPropStg.DeleteMultiple(1, psProp);
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exp.Message, "Error on DeleteMutiple");
}
```

**Explanation:** when **PreserveSig** is **false** you can omit the returned *HRESULT* value, but internally this value is actually checked, so if *HRESULT* is different from *S_OK* an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this enum to define OK, it is from [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/HRESULT.html):

```
enum HRESULT : long
{
S_FALSE = 0x0001,
S_OK = 0x0000,
E_INVALIDARG = 0x80070057,
E_OUTOFMEMORY = 0x8007000E
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`HRESULT` is simply an unsigned 32bit integer value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx). You can build your own constants class to help you make these comparisons:

```
public static class HResults
{
    public static readonly int S_OK = 0;
    public static readonly int STG_E_ACCESSDENIED =  unchecked((int)0x80030005);
}
```

Used like:

```
if (HResults.S_OK == FPropStg.DeleteMultiple(1, psProp))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but it gives me an error. It says "If statement has integer on the left side and void on the right side". I arrive at the same situation. :/ your answer is similar to what I tried earlier , if( FPropStg.DeleteMultiple(1, psProp) == VSConstants.S_OK). I was getting the same error that void and integer can not be compared.

Comment: I got two questions solved 1st and 3rd by your answer.Thanks. any idea for the 2nd question? i.e. void and integer problem ?