# How to obtain the current titlebar color

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to retrieve the current titlebar color?

I have a panel that sits directly under the titlebar (with shortcut icons) and it would be nice if it was the same color.

EDIT:

I just want the titlebar to match the area imidiately below it so it is all the same colour. The way it currently looks is two distinct shades of grey.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the (legacy) Win32 Active Titlebar color - or the Windows Vista DWM color?

Comment: Not sure. I just want to match the current colour, whatever it may be or set to, to a panel under the title. SystemColors.Control is too dark and SystemColors.Menu is too light.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in C# to retrieve the current titlebar color?

If you're asking about the old Win32 `COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION` color then in .NET Framework and .NET 5+ (and maybe .NET Core?) you can use `System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption` - if you're drawing text on top of that then use `ActiveCaptionText`.

If you're after the DWM color then you'll need to use `DwmGetColorizationColor`:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern void DwmGetColorizationColor( out UInt32 colorizationColor, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] out Boolean colorizationOpaqueBlend );
}
```

(`PreserveSig = false` [is what allows this to be `void`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145585/checking-the-return-value-from-a-method-for-an-hresult-of-s-ok) so we don't need to faff around with parsing `HRESULT` in C#)

You'll need to bitshift `colorizationColor` to get the RGBA values out.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of which bit I need to check for?